# jQuery Mobile: Debugging Touch events, issue with data-position="fixed"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Afternoon,

My question is about how to debug touch events when using jQuery Mobile. I'm working on a mobile site (temporary test server here: http://afonsogomes.com/id) using jQuery Mobile with a fixed header (data-position="fixed") that the user can tap to hide or tap to show.

I don't know what I did wrong but all of a sudden the site lost this ability.

Searching jquery mobile demos and docs already tried a few things like data-tap-toggle="true" but without any sucess. Also the console of firebug gives me no red lights what so ever.

Solving this problem is kind of secondary to my question tho it would also be great. I'd love to know how can I debug touch events being fired or not.

Thanks all in advance

Comment: You would log the event to the console to ensure it's firing. Did you do that? Also, show the code in question, or this just basically looks like, 'I don't want to pay anyone to fix something I don't understand so hopefully you guys will just give me teh c0dez'

Comment: well ... This is my first mobile site using jQuery mobile, I didn't even know that if i used data-position="fixed" option the framework would set the tap to hide/show thing.

Comment: That's the thing bro. I'm not asking anyone to fix my code cause I don't even know where this event is triggered. Firebug gives me no errors in the code! This thingy just stopped working and I'd like to know steps i can take to debug it

Comment: The header in question is the one that says `Innodouro`. When I click this header, nothing occurs. If I click the `three horizontal lines` we get a panel from the left. If i click the x, panel closes. If I click the `search icon` on right, a panel on the right opens, if I click the x, the panel closes. What am I missing. I'm testing this on an iPad, for note.

Comment: in Jquery mobile the header slides up and down of the viewport if the user taps any blank space of the page's body. This was working ok and now isn't!

Comment: `console.log($.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled())`. What is returned?

Comment: TypeError: $.mobile.fixedToolbars is undefined

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29759/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-afonso-gomes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off all you are searching your problem on a wrong place.

You have broke one of a main rules of web development "Don't mess with original code!".

Your problem is not in javascript, your problem is in css. I have downloaded your page source and traced an error to :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
```

If you replace this line with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
```

everything works just fine. Unfortunately your css is a mixed mess so you will need to untangle it by yourself. This is not a critique but in the future don't mix different css files and your own.

Comment: Guilty as charged for mixing css files. but i didn't mess with the original jquery mobile css file. i just incorporated it inside my own to reduce http requests and removed all transition related css to make it smaller.

Comment: Something is messing with an original css, I would have looked at it myself but there's so much of it.

Comment: Found it! In my byte greedy driven attempt to reduce the base CSS as much as possible, removing all the transitions related rules (as I'm not using ajax page transitions) I failed to understand the header sliding up and down also make use of some of these rules. Sorry all for this lammy lamme question. Let the down votes begin!